# How to use laravel query builder 'when' operator targeting a column of the same result set

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel

Maybe I'm trying to accomplish this in the wrong way but I need to able to insert an if condition inside a laravel query builder:

```
$name = $request->input('name');
$query = DB::connection('dbconxz')
            ->table('all_items')->select('name', 'price', 'description', 'type', 'quantity', 'exempt')
            ->where('name', 'like', "%{$name}%")
            ->when('??? how to target the *TYPE* column?'== 'Inventory', function ($query) {
                return $query->where('quantity', '>', 0);
            })
            ->get();
```

I have an ajax auto complete that is searching the table all_items and returning the collection of the items where the name is LIKE what the user is typing.. *typical ajax autocomplete from database*.  Now my problem is that the column named "type" some of the rows have the word 'Inventory' and I wish to only include that result if the quantity of that row is > 0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's figure this out with regular SQL.

```
SELECT name, price, description, type, quantity, exempt
FROM all_items
WHERE name LIKE %$name%
    AND (
        (
            type = 'Inventory'
            AND quantity > 0
        )
        OR type <> 'Inventory'
    );
```

Then, using Laravel:

```
$name = $request->input('name');
$query = DB::connection('dbconxz')
    ->table('all_items')->select('name', 'price', 'description', 'type', 'quantity', 'exempt')
    ->where('name', 'like', "%{$name}%")
    ->where(function ($query) {
        return $query->where([
            'type', '=', 'Inventory',
            'quantity', '>', 0
        ])
        ->orWhere('type', '<>', 'Inventory');
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

`when` is used when you want a condition in the application. But here you need a condition for the database server so do something like the below

```
$query = DB::connection('dbconxz')
            ->table('all_items as t1')->select('name', 'price', 'description', 'type', 'quantity', 'exempt')
            ->where('name', 'like', "%{$name}%")
            ->where(function ($query1) {
                $query1->where(function ($query2) { $query2->where('type', '==', 'Inventory')->where('quantity', '>', 0); })
                      ->orWhere('type', '<>', 'Inventory')
            })
            ->get();
```